In Access, is there a way I can let users choose the entries they are interested in in a form and then generate a report showing all the entries?
So basically, I've created a form that displays the product details one by one. I want to make it such that, if they're interested in the product shown, they can click a button or a check box in the same page. After going through all the products, they can then close the form and a report would be generated showing all of the products they're interested in.
Is there a way to make this work? Any other suggestions/workarounds would be appreciated too. Thank you!
Tried adding buttons but I don't know enough to make it work

have you seen this: https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/how-to-add-a-checkbox-on-a-continuous-form.315623/post-1741143

You will need some VBA for this purpose. Put this code in your On Click event of the button for generating report:
DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReportName", acPreview, , "Interested = True", acWindowNormal

"Interested" being the name of the column where you store data from the checkbox.
